# android layout not displaying, but it displays in ide

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout file which displays perfectly in the IDE view and it doesnt have any errors out lined. But when i run it the activity is blank...

Why could this be?

[image]

There is a screen shot of the emulators view and the view in the IDE:

the xml code for it follows below:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This a pictuer of a hamburger" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="R41.24" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This a pictuer of a hamburger" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="R41.24" />
</TableRow>
```

Activity Code:

```
public class FoodMenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.food_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What did you put in your Activity code?

Comment: Are you using setContentView?

Comment: Have you implemented the code to load the quick contact badge? Have you added contacts in the emulator?

Comment: No, I just want an image really. Could that be the problem? wont it just show the default image ?

Comment: The `layout_height` of your `EditText`s should probably be set to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my `QuickContactBadge` , I changed it to a `ImageView` and it worked.